# Executing spark streaming actions sequentially

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am reading data from kafka in spark streaming application and doing two actions

1. Insert dstreams into hbase table A
2. Update another hbase table B

I want to make sure that for each rdd in dstream
Insert into hbase table A will happen before update operation on hbase table B (above two action happen sequentially for each rdd)

How to achieve this in spark streaming application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my knowledge you can perform the above task in the below way

This will be performed in sequential manner

```
 recordStream.foreachRDD{rdd => { //this will be Dstream RDD Records from kafka
 val record = rdd.map(line => line.split("\\|")).collect 
 record.foreach {recordRDD => { //Write the code for Insert in hbase}
 record.foreach {recordRDD => { //Write the code for Update in hbase}
```

**Hope this Helps**

Comment: here, Does second foreach loop will start only after first foreach loop finishes

Answer (score 0):

Update both tables sequentially in single `rdd.foreach()`. It will be executed in sequential manner given you have handled exceptions properly.

This behavior is backed by the fact that its DAG will be executed in the same stage sequentially.